transaction reverted when calling swapExactETHForToken on uniswapRouter02
currently, I'm trying to swap eth for an erc20 token and the transaction gets reverted every time, not quite sure what I'm missing, i pre-approved some allowance for the router02 to spend on my behalf, to see if it will help but nothing, the transition still gets reverted.
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.BASE_RPC);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.WALLET0, provider);

//contract router instance
const abi = require('../ABIs/uniswapV2Router02.json')
const router02Add = defi.uniswapV2Router02 //object with dierent contract addresses
const router = new ethers.Contract(router02Add, abi, signer)

//facotry intance
const factAbi = require('../ABIs/v2FactoryABI.json')
const factoryAdd = defi.uniswapv2Factory
const factory = new ethers.Contract(factoryAdd, factAbi, signer)


//tokens1
let luna = '0x698dc45e4f10966f6d1d98e3bfd7071d8144c233' //change fo any other token
let weth = '0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006'


async function swapv2(token1){

    //confirm pair exisit
    // function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    let pairAddress = await factory.getPair(weth,token1);
    if (!pairAddress) {
        console.error('Pair not found for WETH-token pair');
        return;
      }

    //pool contract intance
    let poolAbi = require('../ABIs/uniswapv2Pair.json')
    let poolContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, poolAbi, signer)

    let lq = await poolContract.getReserves() //element 0 is weth
    let lq1 = ethers.formatUnits(lq[0])

    //if weth liquidity is less than a ETH probably not a good idea to buy
    if(lq1 < 1)
    {
        console.log('liquidity to low')
    }else {
        // function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)

        let amountOutMin = ethers.parseUnits('1', 18)
        let path = [weth,token1]
        const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 2; // Deadline in 2 minutes

        //weth contrtact instance
        const wethAbi = require('../ABIs/WETHABI.json')
        let WETH = new ethers.Contract(weth, wethAbi, signer);

        //initialize the swap
        let tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(amountOutMin , path, signer.address, deadline,  { value : ethers.parseEther('0.0005'),gasLimit: 25000})

        //wait for transaction completion
        await tx.wait()

        console.log('transaction completed\n',tx)
    }
}
swapv2(luna)

and transaction gets reverted every time, appreciate any help

i looked at the transaction failed in baseScan , and notice it was failing cus it was running out of gas
https://basescan.org/tx/0xa3d18b809fb3221de12de77d74027597e2de7822965b681ad50bb6d2be8ab6e6
so just bumped up the gas limit:
{ value : ethers.parseEther('0.0005'),gasLimit: 300000}

and this is the successful one:
https://basescan.org/tx/0xc3ce94454f788771556d4cb6025c6a35d72f9e009b9ab6c98c7cb21c6ec8b4ec
